# Why am I getting exactly same results from lm and ICR?

Tags: statistical-significance, hydrology

I am comparing different prediction models to predict flooding by R. For models I have Linear regression (lm), Index flood (IF) approach and Independent component regression (ICR). The first two have worked fine. The ICR is giving me exactly same result as the lm model no matter how I do it. I have 8 different predictors for 8 cases. I am using leave one out validation to validate my models. My question is am I supposed to get similar result from lm and ICR if the number and type of predictor variables remain same? Say I am using catchment area, shape factor and rainfall intensity in my linear regression model and I have transformed these exact variables through Independent Component Analysis to get my Independent Components and used them in my ICR, would I get the same prediction from both models?